# Getting week started date using MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime, group-by

If I have MySQL query like this, summing word frequencies per week:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(`city`), 
  SUM(`officers`), 
  SUM(`uk`), 
  SUM(`wednesday`), 
  DATE_FORMAT(`dateTime`, '%d/%m/%Y') 
FROM myTable 
WHERE dateTime BETWEEN '2011-09-28 18:00:00' AND '2011-10-29 18:59:00' 
GROUP BY WEEK(dateTime)
```

The results given by MySQL take the first value of column dateTime, in this case 28/09/2011 which happens to be a Saturday.

Is it possible to adjust the query in MySQL to show the date upon which the week commences, even if there is no data available, so that for the above, 2011-09-28 would be replaced with 2011/09/26 instead? That is, the date of the start of the week, being a Monday. Or would it be better to adjust the dates programmatically after the query has run?

The dateTime column is in format 2011/10/02 12:05:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do it in SQL but it would be better to do it in your program code as it would be more efficient and easier. Also, while MySQL accepts your query, it doesn't quite make sense - you have `DATE_FORMAT(dateTime, '%d/%m/%Y')` in select's field list while you group by `WEEK(dateTime)`. This means that the DB engine has to select random date from current group (week) for each row.  Ie consider you have records for `27.09.2011`, `28.09.2011` and `29.09.2011` - they all fall onto same week, so in the final resultset only one row is generated for those three records. Now which date out of those three should be picked for the DATE_FORMAT() call? Answer would be somewhat simpler if there is `ORDER BY` in the query but it still doesn't quite make sense to use fields/expressions in the field list which aren't in `GROUP BY` or which aren't aggregates. You should really return the week number in the select list (instead of DATE_FORMAT call) and then in your code calculate the start and end dates from it.

Comment: Not sure I quite understand your answer. MySQL is giving me the  dateTime of the first row for each week's GROUP BY, and for each dateTime in the results, I'm then using DATE_FORMAT to format that dateTime.

Comment: @MrMorgan, ain means that your query has a logical error. It is indeterminate. The group by will throw multiple rows together, but only **one** of those rows will be shown. Your selected non-aggregate fields should always be functionally dependent upon the group by clause. The easiest way to do this is to repeat **all** non-aggregate selects in the group by clause.

Comment: @MrMorgan See my updated answer, hope it explains it better now. It so happens that MySQL picks the date you want but it is implementation detail you really shouldn't relay on!

Comment: @Johan: A pity that this removes the dateTime value from the field list though it can be replaced programmatically as AIN suggests.

Comment: What Johan means is that if you want to use `DATE_FORMAT(dateTime, '%d/%m/%Y')` in field list you should also add it to the `GROUP BY` (or in this case adding `dateTime` into group by would do). But this would give your different resultset than the one you want so you have to use some different approach...